# Maven Surefire is Not Respecting TestNG Listeners in Property Tag

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run listeners with Maven + Surefire + TestNG as per documentation: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Using_Custom_Listeners_and_Reporters

Here is relevant code from my POM:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT.class</include>
                        </includes>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                                <!-- disabling default listeners is optional -->
                                <value>false</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>listener</name>
                                <value>cucumber.poc.config.LocalWebDriverListener</value>
                            </property>

                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

[Here is my project structure img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19giD.png)

My Tests are running fine, but my TestNG Listener is not being invoked. Please help!

Comment: Integration Tests should be done by using maven-failsafe-plugin instead of Maven Surefire plugin.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/testng.html#Using_Custom_Listeners_and_Reporters

I have tried this as well not working for me.

Comment: When I run with testng.xml same listener work fine, but when i use this configuration mentioned above, listener doesn't invoke. See If I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you tested to configure debugging output of TestNG `surefire.testng.verbose`?

Comment: @HammadHost your sure-fire reports should be in `target` folder if you are running from maven, is that where you are referring?

Comment: @HammadHost - How are you determining that your listener is not getting executed ? Also you might want to share the verbose output as pointed out above.

Comment: kindly have a look, complete code: https://github.com/HammadHost/poc_maven_sf_fs_testNG_listneres It doesn't show any verbose even though they are properly configured as per documentation. While when I use xml for execution it invoke listener and show verbose logs as well. and How I know that listener is executed or not is by using simple System.out

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Please have a look

Comment: Simplest Skeleton, Surefire is not running testng Listeners for me, someone please help. https://github.com/HammadHost/poc_testng_surefire

Comment: @hammadhost - The surefire listeners are definitely running. I ran your test project and I can see them printing the sysout statements. Please double check. I cloned `git@github.com:HammadHost/poc_testng_surefire.git`

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GttOv.png

Tried again, with simple 'mvn clean test' from macOS Sierra terminal, it didn't print listener's output for me. Any hint where could my environment go wrong!

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan
Just created fresh environment, fresh vm + intelliJ + JDK9 still same results.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/56ter.png

Comment: Strangely I created fresh environment on Ubuntu and listener did executed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGOwv.png

What could be wrong in macOS :(

Comment: Well I figured out:
- It works with JDK8
- It doesn't work with JDK9
Reverting back to jdk8.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1450